# How to match all different symbols from empty string with RegularExpression attribute in MVC

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have a strange problem - I try to match all possible symbols about my UserName TextBox in my Login page and this attribute must be throw your ErrorMessage when the current box is empty. I tried with   `[^.+$]`   but this regex matched just one symbol, after that  I tryed with   `^[.+]$`   and this matched literal sense of char "." (dot). I tried many other cases and regexes, but the attribute do not give me desired result.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check that there is a value on your textbox, use the `[Required]` attribute.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Your error message when the textbox is empty")]
public string YourProperty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is check that the input is not Empty,  Efrain's answer is the best approach.

If for some reason you want to use RegEx,  the below would do it.

```
[RegularExpression("^(?!\s*$).+", ErrorMessage = "Invalid User Name")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Comment: I know that the best approach is use the [Required] attribute, but in my case I need to use RegEx. Thanks by your answer, but and this regex don't work in my case. Regards

Comment: Can you please clarify not working?  Is it not throwing an error for blank input?  Is it incorrectly throwing an error for a valid input?

Comment: Also are you using client validation or server validation?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the square brackets in the regular expression:

```
^.+$


[RegularExpression("^.+$", ErrorMessage = "Empty username")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```